# why it doensn't return children of workflow package by CMIS?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share, cmis

Alfresco version 4.2e

I started "Review And Approve Workflow" on specific file, assigning the task on a user.

Then I got the user task by REST:

```
{
.....
 "bpm_package": "workspace://SpacesStore/db7ec6c5-4dfe-44fd-a7fd-271526237c86",
....
{
```

According to http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/workflow-rest-api-and-workflow-content-12022010-0903

It supposed that I can retrieve the workflow package children by CMIS REST, but when I called it by:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/SpacesStore/i/db7ec6c5-4dfe-44fd-a7fd-271526237c86/children
```

It returns response with no children:

```
<feed>
   ....
  <title>db7ec6c5-4dfe-44fd-a7fd-271526237c86 Children</title>
  <updated>2014-03-05T12:12:46.356+03:00</updated>
  <opensearch:totalResults>0</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage>-1</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
  <cmisra:numItems>0</cmisra:numItems>
</feed>
```

Please, could someone advise me ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem may be that the association is bpm:packageContains instead of cm:contains. CMIS doesn't support parent-child relationships (other than folders containing documents). I believe the only parent-child relationship defined by Alfresco that is supported by CMIS may be cm:contains.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but how can I get/update the workflow package contents remotely (out of alfresco)?

Comment: To whom it may concern, 

to update task package remotely Send POST request on 

  /alfresco/s/api/task/[taskId]/formprocessor

Request body is:
{
"assoc_packageItems_added":"",
"assoc_packageItems_removed":"workspace://SpacesStore/b5d41e38-e4d7-4ef5-b093-afb195b859ea"
}
-------------------

to get it, send post on POST /alfresco/s/api/formdefinitions
with body (replace task id):

{
"itemKind":"task",
"itemId":"activiti$626",
"fields":["packageItems"]
}